# How to add extra space inside of a table

Tags: tables, spacing, boxes

I wrote a simple table with this commands:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Parametro} &  \multicolumn{1}{ c| }{Espressione} \\ \hline \hline
$T_{ref}$ & $T_{0}$ \\ \hline
$P_{ref}$ & $P_{0}$ \\ \hline
$M_{ref}$ & $m_{O_{2}}$ \\ \hline
$L_{ref}$ & $\frac{K_{B}T_{ref}}{\sqrt{2}\pi Rc^{2}P_{0}}$ \\ \hline
$V_{ref}$ & $\sqrt{\frac{K_{B}T_{ref}}{m_{ref}}}$ \\ \hline
$t_{ref}$ & $\frac{L_{ref}}{V_{ref}}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:Parametri_Riferimento}
\caption{Parametri di riferimento}% title of Table
\end{table}
```

and the output looks like this:
[image]

**Here is my problem**: as you can see some of my equations inside of the table don't have enough space around them; therefore part of the letters interfere with the separating lines and it doesn't look too clear and nice to see.

**Here is my question**: is there a way to add some extra space within the same box in order to have more distance between the formulas and the box upper and lower boundaries?

Comment: Add `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` right after `\centering`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a little hack using the `\rule` command. The `\rule` command in normal use produces a simple black box with the following parameters `\rule[depth]{width}{height}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Parametro} &  \multicolumn{1}{ c| }{Espressione} \\ \hline \hline
$T_{\text{ref}}$ & $T_{0}$ \\ \hline
$P_{\text{ref}}$ & $P_{0}$ \\ \hline
$M_{\text{ref}}$ & $m_{O_{2}}$ \\ \hline
$L_{\text{ref}}$ & $\frac{K_{B}T_{\text{ref}}}{\sqrt{2}\pi Rc^{2}P_{0}}$\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex} \\ \hline
$V_{\text{ref}}$ & $\sqrt{\frac{K_{B}T_{\text{ref}}}{m_{\text{ref}}}}$\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{6ex} \\ \hline
$t_{\text{ref}}$ & $\frac{L_{\text{ref}}}{V_{\text{ref}}}$\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:Parametri_Riferimento}
\caption{Parametri di riferimento}% title of Table
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The "ref" subscripts ought to be typeset using text rather than math italics.

Comment: @Mico Aye Sir! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution with an "open" look, i.e., with no vertical rules and far fewer horizontal rules. The look is achieved by using the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package.

Some additional suggestions:

- Since all cells in the table (except the two in the header row) should be typeset in math rather than text mode, it's convenient to use an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment. That way, you can get away with typing far fewer `$` symbols.
- The material in the right-hand column should be typeset in display rather than text style. Rather than having to type `\displaystyle` repeatedly, it's handy to define the column up front as needing to typeset its contents in display math style.
- The repeated "ref" subscript should be set in text italics rather than math italics.
- Since the two columns are of type `c`, it's not necessary to encase the material in the two header cells inside `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` statements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,array}
\newcommand\itref{\textit{ref}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
$\begin{array}{ @{} c  >{\displaystyle}c @{} }
\toprule
\text{Parametro} &  \text{Espressione} \\
\midrule
T_{\itref} & T_{0} \\
P_{\itref} & P_{0} \\
M_{\itref} & m_{O_{2}} \\[1ex]
L_{\itref} & \frac{K_{B}T_{\itref}}{\sqrt{2}\pi Rc^{2}P_{0}} \\[2.5ex]
V_{\itref} & \sqrt{\frac{K_{B}T_{\itref}}{m_{\itref}}} \\ [2ex]
t_{\itref} & \frac{L_{\itref}}{V_{\itref}} \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\caption{Parametri di riferimento}% title of Table
\label{tab:Parametri_Riferimento}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Either use `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` (as azetina already suggested) or `booktabs` package and the `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule` which provide some better vertical spacings

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Parametro} &  \multicolumn{1}{ c| }{Espressione} \tabularnewline 
\midrule \midrule
$T_{ref}$ & $T_{0}$ \tabularnewline
 \midrule
$P_{ref}$ & $P_{0}$ \tabularnewline 
\midrule
$M_{ref}$ & $m_{O_{2}}$ \tabularnewline 
\midrule
$L_{ref}$ & $\frac{K_{B}T_{ref}}{\sqrt{2}\pi Rc^{2}P_{0}}$ \tabularnewline 
\midrule
$V_{ref}$ & $\sqrt{\frac{K_{B}T_{ref}}{m_{ref}}}$ \tabularnewline 
\midrule
$t_{ref}$ & $\frac{L_{ref}}{V_{ref}}$ \tabularnewline 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:Parametri_Riferimento}
\caption{Parametri di riferimento}% title of Table
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Parametro} &  \multicolumn{1}{ c| }{Espressione} \tabularnewline 
\hline \hline
$T_{ref}$ & $T_{0}$ \tabularnewline
 \hline
$P_{ref}$ & $P_{0}$ \tabularnewline 
\hline
$M_{ref}$ & $m_{O_{2}}$ \tabularnewline 
\hline
$L_{ref}$ & $\frac{K_{B}T_{ref}}{\sqrt{2}\pi Rc^{2}P_{0}}$ \tabularnewline 
\hline
$V_{ref}$ & $\sqrt{\frac{K_{B}T_{ref}}{m_{ref}}}$ \tabularnewline 
\hline
$t_{ref}$ & $\frac{L_{ref}}{V_{ref}}$ \tabularnewline 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:Parametri_Riferimento::arraystretch}
\caption{Parametri di riferimento}% title of Table
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see (from the second table), that even the rather large value of `1.5` does not look very nice.

Perhaps, it's even better to omit the horizontal lines

Comment: The first one looks awful with those broken vertical rules.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Yes, I'll try to remove the problem

Comment: If you remove all those vertical rules and all but three (at the top, below headers, at the bottom) horizontal rules, I think the table looks better.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I am no friend of those lines at all, but I don't want to change the complete look. If the OP wants to have lines, he should get them ;-) Oh, I just saw, the other answer was accepted.

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence My answer is just a quick hack. I invite you to update your answer in the event it best answers the question.

Comment: @azetina: A nice hack however. I will look later on my solution.