# How to set row height on a table

Tags: tables, tabls

My Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2.1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabls}
\usepackage{diagbox,pict2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{c}|}
    \hline
    2007 & 2008 & 2009 & 2010 & 2011\\
    \hline
    08.04 & 23.03 & 12.04 & 04.04 & 24.04 \\
    27.05 & 11.05 & 31.05 & 23.05 & 12.06 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

How to the output file as the following:

[image]

Is the **tabls** package obsolete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the dirty hack of using `\rule{depth}{width}{height}` in particular row to change the appearance of the row itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232202/how-to-add-extra-space-inside-of-a-table
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{5}{c}|}
    \hline
    2007 & 2008 & 2009 & 2010 & 2011\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{6ex}\\
    \hline
    08.04 & 23.03 & 12.04 & 04.04 & 24.04 \rule[1ex]{0pt}{3ex}\\
    27.05 & 11.05 & 31.05 & 23.05 & 12.06 \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{3ex}\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

with which you can get

[image]

> Note: I dont know about the status regarding the package `tabls`. IMO, it should be a second question instead.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I understand your question 100%. Personally, I feel tables made with the `booktabs` package look more modern. Here's an example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2.1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{diagbox,pict2e}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
        \toprule
        2007 & 2008 & 2009 & 2010 & 2011\\
        \midrule
        08.04 & 23.03 & 12.04 & 04.04 & 24.04 \\
        27.05 & 11.05 & 31.05 & 23.05 & 12.06 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP also needs vertical bars.

Comment: True. He also talks about something being obsolete, and I think there's little thing in the world which is more obsolete than vertical bars in a table.

Comment: thats mainly opinion based and is mainly of personal interests 
;)